# ngRoute SyntaxError: Unexpected token < not solved by adding "/"

Tags: angularjs, ngroute, angularjs-ng-route

Good afternoon everyone,

I started AngularJS a few days ago and, if I usually find my all answers here, I have a mysterious error...

**Here is the evil error:**

*Error in event  for (unknown): SyntaxError: Unexpected  <
extensions::uncaught_exception_handler*

**Here is for my code:**

HTML (index.html)

```
<script src="/app/main.controller.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="/app/controllers/test.controller.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

<a href="#/">Home</a>
<a href="#/design">Design</a>
```

ANGULAR (main.controller.js)

```
function RouteProvider ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider

    .when("/", {
    templateUrl: "/app/views/home.html",
    controller: "homeCtrl"
    })

    .when("/design", {
    templateUrl: "/app/views/design.html",
    controller: "testCtrl"
    })

    .otherwise({
    redirectTo: "/"
    });
}
```

STRUCTURE

```
index.html
/app
 main.controller.js
 /controllers
 /views
```

This is the part of the code concerned by my route config.

The error happens whenever I activate the links above...

Thank you for your time!

(It's my first post, sorry if it's messy and if you need more code juste ask and I'll add it :])

Comment: Normally when that happens to me, it is because I have my server set to return my index page when it can't find anything.  Then, when I load javascript with a bad URL, it loads that HTML file instead.

Comment: Have you included the actual AngularJS source in `index.html`?

Comment: Ankh - No the AngularJS code is in a js file if it's what you mean :/

Comment: Dave Bush - It's a local server, I configured it in a way to target the index.html or the index.php file, do you think it's because of this?